# General error: 3730 Cannot drop table 'questionnaires' referenced by a foreign key constraint (SQL: drop table if exists `questionnaires`) Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem when I rollback my boards. It is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3730 Cannot drop table 'questionnaires' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'questions_questionnaire_id_foreign' on table 'questions'. (SQL: drop table if exists `questionnaires`)
```

For this I have 2 tables involved, which is Questionnaire and Question.

`Question`

```
lass CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('questionnaire_id');

      $table->text('description');
      $table->text('iframe');
      $table->text('image')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  public function down(){
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropColumn('questionnaire_id');
      $table->dropForeign('questions_questionnaire_id_foreign');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
  }
}
```

`Questionnaire`

```
class CreateQuestionnairesTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::create('questionnaires', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
      $table->string('title');
      $table->string('description');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  public function down(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('questionnaires');
  }
}
```

And then add the questionnaire FK to the question table. Alter table

```
class AddToQuestionnaireIdToQuestionsTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('questionnaire_id')->references('id')->on('questionnaires')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
  }
  public function down(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
  }
}
```

However when I rollback I get the aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dropping the question table in the wrong place. You should rollback only what you did roll forward.

`Question`: if you created a table, here you drop the table.

```
Class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('questionnaire_id');

            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('iframe');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

`ForeigKey`: if you created a column and/or foreign key, drop then here.

```
class AddToQuestionnaireIdToQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('questionnaire_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('questionnaires')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('questions_questionnaire_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('questionnaire_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error ... Should I delete the database and do a migrate from scratch?

Comment: Yes, try that. If it works, probably the migrations table was out of sync. It can happen when this types of errors are generated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete a table and get a foreign key error, do as the code below in SQL

```sql
set foreign_key_checks=0;
drop table `yourSchema`.`yourTable`;
```

Comment: It's a hack, not the solution.